# Pseudocode for SQL query

Tags: sql, database

Hi guys i have the following question,

Assume tables foo(a int, b int) and bar(a int, b int) and assume you are given a stream ‘TableReader’ that reads rows from a table that has the following methods:
tr.next() returns the next row of a type ‘row’ from the stream if there is a next row or null if there are no more rows. 
Assume columns can be accessed using row[columnName]. For example, to read rows from foo, you have to do the following:
    foo_stream = TableReader(‘foo’);
    row = foo_stream.next();

row[‘a’] will return the value of column a and row[‘b’] will return the value of column b.

Write a pseudocode to compute the results of the following SQL query which should return a list of rows:
    select foo.a, foo.b, bar.a, bar.b 
    from foo, bar 
    where foo.a = bar.a 
    and foo.b <=100;

Can anyone help me on this ?
 The solution i tried is:

```
Foo_stream = TableReader(‘foo’);
Bar_stream = tableReader(‘bar’);


While(foo_stream.next())
{ 
  {
   While(bar_stream.next())
   {
     Row_foo = foo_stream.next();
     Row_Bar =bar_stream.next();
    {
    If((row_foo[a] equals row_bar[a]) AND (row_foo[b] < = 100)) 

          {
    Then  print row_foo[a],row_foo[b], row_bar[a],           row_bar[b]
          }
       }
  }
}
```

But the above solution is of complexity O(n2), any better solution is appreciated.

Comment: This is why real databases have indexes, they aren't accessed sequentially.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a theoretical database, not practical programming. It probably belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There are a couple of logic issues in your code as well: 1, as you use `.next()` in your while condition you're hopping over 1 row for every row you read and 2, why are your 2 read operations inside the inner while loop?

Comment: That's true, but can anyone help with some other psudo code which doe snot have two while so that the complexity reduces from O(n2) to O(n) or nlogn.

Comment: I have kept both of the read operations inside second while so that its local to the block, if i keep first read in first while then i dont think it will be accessible from inside of second while block.

Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: It's pseudocode so anything can happen, but in no programming language I know that would be the case, and this version is just wrong - both tablereaders hop through the tables side by side and that's most definitely not what you want - you'll only find matching rows if they happen to be in the same location (rownumber) in the two tables.

Comment: What solution you would write for this one, i will appreciate the help.

Comment: outer while, read table a.  inner while, read table b.  on every record test your condition and print result.  Won't get a whole lot more efficient than that...

Comment: Oh you mean: 

    While(foo_stream.next())
    { 
      Row_foo = foo_stream.next();
     {
      While(bar_stream.next())
      {
         Row_Bar =bar_stream.next();
       {
        If((row_foo[a] equals row_bar[a]) AND (row_foo[b] < = 100)) 
          {
           Then  print row_foo[a],row_foo[b], row_bar[a],bow_bar[b]
          } 
         }
       }
     }

Comment: This seems an awful lot like homework.

Comment: yes it is. was asked during an interview.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
Foo_stream = TableReader(‘foo’);
Foo_row = Foo_stream.next();
Foo_hash = New HashSet<Foo_row[a].typeof, Foo_row.typeof>();

Do
{
    if (Foo_row[b] <= 100)
    {
        Foo_hash.Add(Foo_row[a], Foo_row);
    }
    if (!foo_stream.next())  { Foo_row = Foo_stream.next(); }
} While(foo_stream.next())

Bar_stream = tableReader(‘bar’);

While(bar_stream.next())
{
    Bar_row = Bar_stream.next();
    if (Foo_hash.Exists(Bar_row[a]))
    {
        Foo_row = Foo_hash(Bar_row[a]);
        print foo_row[a],foo_row[b], bar_row[a],bar_row[b];
    }
}
```

This is called the HashMap method, and is O(n), though it uses a relatively large amount of memory.

There is also the MergeSort method, which is O(NlogN) unless the streams are already sorted on [a].  It requires somewhat less memory than the HashMap method.

Finally there is the method that you used, which is called the Nested Loops method, and as you said, is O(n^2), but has the advantage of needing very little memory.